# RN mock dismissKeyboard module

Tags: testing, reactjs, react-native, mocha.js

In my RN application I am importing the following module:

```
const dismissKeyboard = require('dismissKeyboard'); /
import dismissKeyboard from 'dismissKeyboard';
```

When running tests I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'dismissKeyboard'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (InputAccessory.js:12:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at loader (/Users/user/dev/app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:126:5)
```

I have tried with sinon:

```
  before(() => {
    sinon.stub('dismissKeyboard', () => {});
  });
```

and also with mockey:

```
mockery.enable();
mockery.mock('dismissKeyboard', () => null) /
mockery.registerMock('dismissKeyboard', () => null)
```

But I still get the same error.

Any suggestions? The dismissKeyboard module is shipped with RN, but somehow being required separately. I am using mocha.

**Update**

I found that dismissKeyboard comes from

> react-native/Libraries/Utilities/dismissKeyboard.js

although even using this full path when trying to mock it did not make any difference, now I am getting a warning about a module within this js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `require` this can easily be mocked with [mock-require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-require). Doesn't appear to work for es6 imports though.

```
var mock = require('mock-require');

mock('dismissKeyboard', function () {
  return 'I\'m a mocked function';
});

var dismissKeyboard = require('dismissKeyboard');

console.log(dismissKeyboard());
```

If you want to mock this across all your tests add it in your setup file (or create one if you haven't already) and use it when running your tests like so:

```
mocha --require setup.js tests
```